# "Play sound through" device in sound settings often not present and requires reboot to reappear

Tags: sound, headphones

When I boot up my computer, sometimes I'm not able to use my headphone jack. When I open sound settings the device is not there. I end up having to reboot the computer to get it to reappear (sometimes 2 or 3 times). What can I do to fix this?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Below the screen shot with the device missing.
[image]

Here after 3 reboots the **Headphones** have appeared. 
[image]

### Edit

Attempted moving around the jack as suggested in the comments, as well as unplugging and plugging back in several times with no luck.

Comment: While in the sound settings window, SLOWLY move the headphone plug around, if the headphones appear/disappear then you probably have a bad headphone jack.

Comment: I'll try that on the next occurrence. For what it's worth I've only had the case for about 2 months.

Comment: @stumblebee I gave that a shot, with no luck.